# Visual Studio Code cannot find Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, settings

I have used my conda install with Spyder without any problems. I now have installed Visual Studio Code and edited the settings.json file with the `python.pythonPath` pointing to  `~/anaconda3/bin/python`. But for some reason whenever I try to run a Python file I keep getting a message: "You don't have an extension for debugging Python." I am using a macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and have the latest installation of Anaconda.

Comment: Have you installed the python extension to VS code? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Sorry @Sefan, my mac already has python installed. Why do I need to add the python extension from the marketplace?

Comment: The extension dose not include python but includes features such as IntelliSense (Pylance), linting, debugging, code navigation, code formatting, refactoring, variable explorer, test explorer for python. Read more on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extention warning will be fixed if you install the [Python Extension](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for VS code. It do not include python but it includes features such as IntelliSense (Pylance), linting, debugging, code navigation, code formatting, refactoring, variable explorer, test explorer.